# Why don't I see Lollypop in the sound indicator menu?

Tags: 16.04, indicator-sound, music-player

I just installed the [Lollypop](https://gnumdk.github.io/lollypop-web/#) (v.0.9.227) music player. All good, but I don't see it in the Ubuntu sound-indicator applet. Is this expected behavior or is something wrong with my system?

I have already restarted my system.

Comment: It's the expected behavior. You can contact the developers with your suggestions.

Comment: Could be off-topic as 3rd part app not in Ubuntuif that's a valid reason, as far as 17.04 it's  not in it either..

Comment: I didn't really understand why this is off-topic. I forgot to mention it, but it refers to Ubuntu 16.04. As for the "3rd-party app", Matlab for example is also 3rd-party but there are hundreds of questions in askubuntu about it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, that [just got fixed](https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop/issues/919).

The desktop file for Lollypop is `org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop` and not `lollypop.desktop`. This should be in the `interested-media-players` list of the `com.canonical.indicator.sound` schema (check with dconf-editor).

An update is already in the [ppa repository](https://launchpad.net/~gnumdk/+archive/ubuntu/lollypop).